# Pushing projects to github

Tags: github

I want to upload a project in git hub and push my project in git hub account?

what does this statement mean:
"We recommend every repository include a README, LICENSE, and .gitignore."
Can someone suggest how to proceed after this?

Comment: This statement means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal Set of Steps:

Assuming you are working on some terminal.

1) Clone the project

```
git clone link-to-your-repo
```

2) Move inside project directory

`cd repo-name`

3) Add files

For adding all files use

```
git add .
```

4) Commit files

```
git commit -m "commit-message"
```

5) Push files to Github

```
  git push -u origin master
```

6) If you haven't setup SSH keys, it will ask for credentials. Enter your credentials.

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Github is recommending to include some files, but these are not required to push your project to a repository.

The three files are `README.md`, a license and a `.gitignore` file.

The `README.md` file is what you will see when viewing the repo and it can contain anything, but a good template of what to include can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/PurpleBooth/109311bb0361f32d87a2).

The license is what specifies how/if the code can be used by other people and any rules that will govern that use.

The `gitignore` file specifies what files git will ignore from including in the repository.  A good description of this file and how to use it can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

These are all optional so after including them/not including them you can just push your code the repository as usual:

`git add .`

`git commit -m "initial commit'`

`git remote add origin <your repo url here>`

`git push -u origin master`